# Disable Submit on Form Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery Validation and have a simple script that verifies my requirements are met. I am wanting to hide the submit button if the form has errors and show the submit if the form has no errors.

My Form HTML is below.

```
<form name="homepage-contact" id="homepage-contact" method="post" action="assets/forms/contact-form.php">
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputName">Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" class="span4" id="inputName" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" class="span4" id="inputEmail" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputContact">Message</label>
                <div class="controls">
                 <textarea id="inputContact" name="message" class="span4"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                  <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success">Contact Us</button>
                </div>
              </div>
        </form>
```

And my JS to validate the form looks like:

```
$(function validate() {

var rules = {
    rules: {
        name: {
            minlength: 2,
            maxlength: 50,
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true, 
            email: true
        },
        message: {
            required: true
            minlength: 10, 
            maxlength: 500
    }
    }
};

$('#homepage-contact').validate(rules);

});
```

I am just wanting to add something to the JS to hide/show the Submit button.

I tried adding: `$('#submit-button').hide();` but right after: `$('#homepage-contact').validate(rules);` but it did nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an event handler for your fields.

Add a class `validate` to fields that are validated by the plugin and add the following script after you call `$('#homepage-contact').validate(rules);`

```
function fieldChanged() {
    $('#submit').toggle($('#homepage-contact').valid());
}

$('.validate').on('change', fieldChanged);

fieldChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#submit-button').css('display', 'none');` to hide

`$('#submit-button').prop('disabled', true);` to disable

Comment: Why would `$('#submit-button').css('display', 'none');` work when the OP tried `$('#submit-button').hide()` and it didn't work?

Comment: client side validation doesn't make sense. you'd better also apply server-side validation.

Comment: @user2371301 - No it won't. The code shown in this answer has no relationship to the validation code at all.

Comment: nnnnnn -- Your right it doesn't although, I did put it in anyways to see what would happen and the submit button never appears:)                            -yuwang -- I am planning on doing server-side validation as well as soon as I figure out how to. any suggested readings?

Comment: I thought your question was about just wanting to know how to -- "...add something to the JS to hide/show the Submit button", therefore, I just briefly wrote how it's done.